# Include a variable in JSON string containing HTML using Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON object containing few messages that I show on a webpage using Javascript.The JSON file is in a different directory and I have full control of it and loaded asynchronously.

There are few scenarios where I have to display different messages and some of them contain dynamic data, which are readily available inside the function.
I need to include these dynamic data inside the string, which I have added using plus signs as below.

```js
{
  "text": {
    "successMsg": "<p class=\"success\">This is the success message. Variable is \" + dynamicData + \"<\/p> "
  }
}


//Pseudocode

function displayMsg() {
  var dynamicData = 'some data'
  if (foo) {
    //code to display the JSON text 

  }
}
```

When I display the message on the page, the variable just parses as a string. The variable contains a value at this point but on the webpage it just displays the text `dyanamicData` as a string.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: JS doesn't have any notion of templatable strings (other than `eval` which you should not use). You'll just have to perform a regular old find / replace

Comment: Thanks Phil - so this way is a 'no go' then :)

Comment: It really depends on where the original JSON strings come from and what level of control you have over that process. There's not enough information or context here to begin formulating a robust answer

Comment: Thanks again @Phil. I have just edited the question. The JSON file is in a different directory and I have full control of it and loaded asynchronously.
There are few scenarios where I have to display different messages and some of them contain dynamic data, which are readily available inside the function.

Comment: The code in your question should reflect how the JSON is loaded. I'd advise using better placeholders in your strings, eg `{{dynamicData}}`. Then you could easily replace them or even use a library like [Moustache](https://mustache.github.io/)

Comment: I might extend that further: rather than having an HTML string, use different properties to define the element and class: `{ el: 'p', class: 'success', text: 'your text' }`, and then build the HTML on the fly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a distinct keyword in the `message` object, and use the `String.replace()` method to replace it.

```js
var message = {
  "text": {
    "successMsg": '<p class="success">This is the success message. Variable is ##dynamicData##<\/p> '
  }
};


function displayMsg(foo, dynamicData, message) {
  let updatedMsg = {
    ...message,
    text: { ...message.text,
      successMsg: message.text.successMsg.replace('##dynamicData##', dynamicData)
    }
  };
  if (foo) {
    console.log(updatedMsg);
  }
}

displayMsg(true, 'some data', message);
```

If you need something more dynamic, you can use an object that maps keywords to values, and a regular expression replacement.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar. Yes, This will definitely work, but I was trying to keep all the message text side of things separately in the JSON file.